# SQL Query - Eliminating rows with logical conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server Query to remove rows with some arithmetical logic. MS SQL

Eg:

```
ID   name  varChar
a1   b1      1
a1   b1      2
a2   b2      4
a2   b2      2
a3   b3      5
a3   b3      8
```

Expected output

```
a1   b1  1
a2   b2  2
a3   b3  5
```

Logic: We need to get for every ID and Name combination, least var_char value (unfortunately it is not int, we have to cast it ).

Please help me in resolving this. I tried working on many logic's but nothing worked.

Comment: select ID, name, MIN(int_value) from YourTable group by Id, name

Comment: Why doesn't  [select id, name, min(int_value) from t group by id, name] work? What does that query produce?

Comment: What if my integer value is stored as VarChar in table?

Comment: It is the reason it is failing

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number as below:

```
Select top (1) with ties * from yourtable
   order by Row_Number() over(partition by Id, [Name] order by convert(int,int_value) )
 --you might require to convert to bigint if your value is bigger and in varchar
```

Or you can do using sub query:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Id, [Name] order by int_value) from yourtable )a
Where a.RowN = 1
```

Output as below:

```
+----+------+-----------+
| Id | Name | int_value |
+----+------+-----------+
| a1 | b1   |         1 |
| a2 | b2   |         2 |
| a3 | b3   |         5 |
+----+------+-----------+
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/YRVL56303)

Comment: I'm still getting the remaining values. int_value is a varchar. Does it change anything?

Comment: 211631022221 ICR0031641 MOH5067 40608217 2016-10-06 00:00:00.000
211631022221 ICR0031641 MOH5067 50003993 2016-12-22 00:00:00.000
211631022221 ICR0031641 MOH5067 50012769 2017-01-19 00:00:00.000
211631022221 ICR0031641 MOH5067 50051378 2017-04-20 00:00:00.000
211713141883 ICR0034591 MOH5067 50036701 2017-03-19 00:00:00.000
211713141883 ICR0034591 MOH5067 50077699 2017-06-22 00:00:00.000

Expeceted output 
211631022221 ICR0031641 MOH5067 40608217 2016-10-06 00:00:00.000
211713141883 ICR0034591 MOH5067 50036701 2017-03-19 00:00:00.000

Both 40608217 and 50036701 are varchars

Comment: Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by ID,DateSettlement order by convert(int,PaymentReference)) from Claims_Ra where ID in ('ICR0031641','ICR0034591'))a
Where a.RowN = 1

Comment: How about dateSettlement column? Does this has date with time? You can try changing in DEMO

Comment: Its working, I did a mistake. thanks a lot Kannan. It worked like a charm.

Comment: ha hha... you can upvote and accept the answer if you are interested

Comment: What if the the value is datetime instead of varchar and int. Can we cast it? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: You can order by datetime itself

Answer (score 0):

You can group by, convert the varchar to an int and take the minimum from that.

```
select ID, name, MIN(convert(int,[varChar])) as minimumVarChar
from [yourtable] t
group by ID, name
order by ID, name;
```

Personally, if that varchar should only contain integers then I would just change the type in the table to an int. Then you don't have to convert it in your queries.

Comment: What if it is DateTime ? rather than varchar or Int? how to address it?

Comment: @MUNNAS You can use [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) also to turn a varchar into a datetime. If you look at that page, you'll notice there are different type numbers for different dateformats.

Comment: @MUNNAS Btw, if your table type is a datetime, then you don't need to convert it. A MIN(datetimefield) will give the minimum datetime.

Comment: Also, you can convert the minimum of a datetime field to a varchar in the format you want. F.e. `convert(varchar(19), MIN(datetimefield), 120)`